# Check whenever the output contain some string. And add it to logical if statement?

Tags: linux, string, bash

So basicly i need to scan my access point every 10 minutes. This job is done by using this command

```
ssid=iw wlan0 scan | grep -E 'MY SSID NAME'
```

The output like this

```
SSID: MY SSID NAME
```

But when i add some if-else using the output command above, it fails

```
if [[ $ssid == "SSID: MY SSID NAME" ]]
then
echo "SSID Detected"
else
echo "SSID NOT Detected"
fi
```

it will return false statement ("SSID NOT Detected"). The fact is, my SSID available and broadcasting.
Need help.
And Thank you :)

Comment: See: [How to set a variable equal to the output from a command in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/3776858)

Comment: Still no luck. Change variable to this : 
ssid=`iw wlan0 scan | grep -E "MY SSID NAME"` (adding backticks) on variable value.
Still go straight to false condition

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: What does `echo "@$ssid@"` print? Any spaces around the string `SSID: MY SSID NAME`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test the exit status of grep instead of the result, that is

```
if iw wlan0 scan | grep -q 'MY SSID NAME'; 
then echo "Detected"; 
else echo "Not Detected"; 
fi
```